# What does it mean if the alias is 'x(d)'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I was wonder why this selects the minimum. I understand that that min picks the smallest number in a set and that I am clearly defining a set to pull it from, it is mostly the `x(d)` that I don't understand. I was not able to rewrite the code on my own because I don't really understand what these aliases are doing. Can anyone explain why that subquery works?
Or even just give references?

```
select (select min(d) 
    from (values
       (convert(date,t.enddate)),
       (convert(date,r.enddate)),
       (convert(date,e.enddate))
    ) x(d)) as enddate, t.name
from team t
join roster r on t.personid = r.personid
join enr e on t.personid = e.personid and r.rosterid = e.rosterid
```

Comment: Do you understand the `VALUES (a), (b), (c)` notation?

Comment: yeah its the same as when you insert more than one value. Or at least the same concept I would imagine.

Comment: It's a bit different - that's actually a set of rows, not a set of column values. Try `SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) AS x(d);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question. The `x(d)` is giving the derived table (which is the `values()` part) a name of `x`, and an output column named `d`. This will work the same way:

```
SELECT (SELECT MIN(derived_column_name)
  FROM (values(...)
) AS derived_table(derived_column_name)) AS enddate, ...
```

Comment: I'm not the OP, but -- I wasn't familiar with this sort of destructuring alias, either. How broadly applicable is it? Can you write `SELECT * FROM my_table t1(c1, c2, c3)` to create local aliases for the columns of `my_table`? And -- do other DBMSes support it?

Comment: @ruakh only with derived tables and CTEs AFAIK. About other DBMS platforms? *shrug*